# loop through table to make json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

if I loop through all the cells in my html table  and add each rowOBj to a new property in the tableOBJ  it looks like this below BUT....

```
        var tableOBJ = {};
        $("table tr").each(function (index, value) {

            var r = new rowOBJ(
                                    $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(),
                                    $(this).find('td').eq(1).text()
                                    );

            tableOBJ[index] = r;

        });


        var p = JSON.stringify(tableOBJ);


p =
    {
    "0":{"name":"fdgd","surname":"ssdt"},
    "1":{"name":"fdsf","surname":"vn"},
    "2":{"name":"dfsb","surname":"mry"},
    "3":{"name":"hsdsdfry","surname":"smh"}
    }
```

How do I make the previous look  make the json look like this

```
    {
    {"name":"fdgd","surname":"ssdt"},
    {"name":"fdsf","surname":"vn"},
    {"name":"dfsb","surname":"mry"},
    {"name":"hsdsdfry","surname":"smh"}
    }
```

Comment: You wouldn't, because what you want is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

would it help if tableOBJ  is an array?

```
var tableOBJ = [];
```

Then in your loop instead of setting the index of an object push the array:

```
tableOBJ.push(r);
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked  and you solved my JSON .net problem to at the same time ----THANK YOU